# Internationalization of python/django program: how to implement placeholder in .po file?

Tags: django, internationalization

E.g. in my django source I have:

```
{% blocktrans %}You are a member since {{sincewhen}}{% endblocktrans %}
```

What should go into the .po file? (django docs don't explain this part as far as I could find)

Is .po format for placeholders universal for use in programs written in different programming languages?

**edit:** I've tried commands

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de -e=html,py
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

This did not work because of a bug that I found and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020432/bug-in-django-admin-py-makemessages-or-xgettext-call-warning-unterminated).

After this was fixed I could get the message files generated with the command above (if you have other file extensions - modify -e option accordingly.

Comment: Only a .pot file eh? Hm... what version of gettext and django and Python are you using?

Comment: @superchink. Thanks. gettext 0.17 django 1.0.2 python 2.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Read this section: [Message files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#message-files)

It explains how to generate .po files and gives an example:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
```

Make sure you read that whole section to get an idea of how to generate/edit these files. Also, if you're looking for a great tool to help you manage your translations (and even use Google translations to use as a starting place), check out [django-rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/).

Comment: yep. thanks I've re-read the whole thing. There is no mention of placeholders in .po files.

thanks for the tip about the rosetta tool.

Comment: When you run the makemessages command, it creates a po file for the specified language, which you can edit manually or using something like rosetta. What is still not clear?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l &lt;target_language&gt;
(or makemessages -a for all languages)
```

That'll automatically create all the **msgid's** in the **po's**, all that's left for you is to fill out the msgstr's.

**.po** is the standard format used by the **gettext** library, which is available in virtually every modern programming language.