# Django template translation in block not possible

Tags: python, django, templates, python-3.x, translation

Using Django 1.7.1 under Python 3.4, I have a problem where I did not find any answer to, despite seeming banal, andhaving seen many similar problems all over the internet. No solution that I understood thus far.

I have a simple django template, boiled down to the essential part. It is a simle "trans"-tag translated string within a *content* block that overrides the *admin/base content* block.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% trans "Entries" %}
{% endblock %}
```

With this I get a *TemplateSyntaxError*:

```
Invalid block tag: 'trans', expected 'endblock'
```

What I learned until now it that you need to use a blocktrans for something like that. But I don't get it - WHY the heck does this not work?
Funny thing is, if I replace the `{% trans "Entries" %}` with a `{{ _("Entries") }}` everything works as expected.
But I need the additional benefits you get with the trans tag.

There are plenty of examples, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938665/818131), which use exactly that pattern above - and it whould work.
Any help welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly you are missing this instruction at the top of your template?

```
{% load i18n %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code

Comment: Bam. This was the answer. You made my day :)

Comment: Also of note is that the tag MUST be in the including template, not the base template

Answer (score 0):

i tried using this command:

```
python manage.py makemessages zh_SG
```

instead of

```
python manage.py makemessages zh-sg
```

(note the underscore and capital letters ending) and also made sure that each app has a locale folder (makemessages may create locale folder outside the apps which is a wrong location)

This worked for me, hope it will help you (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833340/5798298)